# Showing converting error for varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I am getting this error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 13
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

This is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
                      DI.DealName AS 'Deal Name',  
    DI.OfferingType AS 'Offering Type',   
    DI.Date AS 'Date',  
    DI.ClassName AS 'Class',  
    ISNULL(Bench,'-') AS 'BM',  
    ISNULL(Guidance,'-') AS 'Guid',  
    DI.Industry AS 'Industry',  
    CAST( (ISNULL(DI.AverageLife,0)) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'WAL',CAST(  ISNULL(DI.ClassSize,0) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Balance',CAST(   REPLACE(ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0),'%','') AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Coupon',  
       CAST(  CASE WHEN CAST(REPLACE(ISNULL(DI.PX2,0),'%','') AS DECIMAL(18,5)) = 0.00 THEN (CASE WHEN ISNULL(CAST(DI.Yield * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,3)),0) = 0 THEN (CASE WHEN (ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+'cpn' = 'cpn' OR ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+'cpn' = '0cpn') THEN '-' ELSE (ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+'cpn')END)ELSE CAST(ISNULL(CAST(DI.Yield * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,3)),0) AS VARCHAR(15))+'%yld' END) ELSE (ISNULL(DI.PX,0)) END AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Spread',  CAST(  ISNULL(CAST(DI.Yield * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,3)),0) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Yield', CAST(  CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DI.Dollar_Px)) = '' THEN 0.00 ELSE CAST(ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Dollar_Px)),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),''),'-',''),'/',''),' ',''),'%cpn',''),0) AS DECIMAL(18,5)) END AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Dollar_Px',  ISNULL(Notes,'') AS Notes,                 
           CAST((FRM.Rating + '/' + KBRARM.Rating) AS VARCHAR(15)) AS 'Rating'  FROM DI_DealIssuancePost DI  
         INNER JOIN DI_CompanyRatingMapping MRM ON MRM.CompanyRatingMappingID = DI.Mdy                   INNER JOIN DI_CompanyRatingMapping SPRM ON SPRM.CompanyRatingMappingID = DI.S_P  
         INNER JOIN DI_CompanyRatingMapping FRM ON FRM.CompanyRatingMappingID = DI.Fitch  
         INNER JOIN DI_CompanyRatingMapping DBRSRM ON DBRSRM.CompanyRatingMappingID = DI.DBRS                 INNER JOIN DI_CompanyRatingMapping KBRARM ON KBRARM.CompanyRatingMappingID = DI.KBRA  

         INNER JOIN DI_WeeklySectors DIWeekly ON DI.Industry = DIWeekly.Sector  

        WHERE DI.IsDeleted = 0              
          AND MRM.IsDeleted = 0  
          AND SPRM.IsDeleted = 0  
          AND FRM.IsDeleted = 0  
          AND DBRSRM.IsDeleted = 0  
          AND KBRARM.IsDeleted = 0  
          AND DI.Date IS NOT NULL   
          AND (CONVERT(DATETIME,DI.Date ,101) >= CONVERT(DATETIME,@StartDate,101))   
          AND (CONVERT(DATETIME,DI.Date ,101) <= CONVERT(DATETIME,@EndDate,101)) AND DI.CurrencyID IN (SELECT * FROM CsvToTable(@Currency)) ORDER BY DI.Date desc
```

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 13
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

And i Can find that here is an error

```
 CAST(  CASE WHEN CAST(REPLACE(ISNULL(DI.PX2,0),'%','') AS DECIMAL(18,5)) = 0.00 THEN (CASE WHEN ISNULL(CAST(DI.Yield * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,3)),0) = 0 THEN (CASE WHEN (ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+'cpn' = 'cpn' OR ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+'cpn' = '0cpn') THEN '-' ELSE (ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+'cpn')END)ELSE CAST(ISNULL(CAST(DI.Yield * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,3)),0) AS VARCHAR(15))+'%yld' END) ELSE (ISNULL(DI.PX,0)) END AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Spread',  CAST(  ISNULL(CAST(DI.Yield * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,3)),0) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Yield', CAST(  CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DI.Dollar_Px)) = '' THEN 0.00 ELSE CAST(ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Dollar_Px)),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),''),'-',''),'/',''),' ',''),'%cpn',''),0) AS DECIMAL(18,5)) END AS VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Dollar_Px',  ISNULL(Notes,'') AS Notes,
```

some one help to solve this error

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: i am sry friends i cant able to past the full code

Comment: micro soft sql server 2014

Comment: The error message says it all. You're trying to convert a non-numeric varchar value to a numeric data type.

Comment: shall i send full code @ jarlh

Comment: Where is the declaration of  `@SQLQuery`? Did you print out your statement? Do you get the error on execution oft this or while building this? Did you try to find the stated location (*line 13*)?

Comment: i am getting the error at this line

Comment: CAST(  CASE WHEN CAST(REPLACE(ISNULL(DI.PX2,0),''%'','''') AS DECIMAL(18,5)) = 0.00 THEN (CASE WHEN ISNULL(CAST(DI.Yield * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,3)),0) = 0 THEN (CASE WHEN (ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+''cpn'' = ''cpn'' OR ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+''cpn'' = ''0c

Comment: No need for all code. Only you can find the non-numeric column value that can't be converted.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Use `PRINT @SQLQuery`  and paste the code into a new window. Then try to take away part of it, or try to use `TRY_CAST` instead of `CAST` (same with `TRY_CONVERT`) This will return a `NULL` instead of an error. You can then search for NULLs in your resultset.

Comment: /*DI_GetCapitalStructure '1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM','8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM','3,4',**1** */ if is use **null** instead of using 1 it showing value but if i use **1** it showing error.

Comment: Ask yourself why you have to do those casts? Why are you storing numeric values in a varchar column? Consider altering the table definitions to write safer code.

Comment: @jarlh, @ shnugo thank for everyone i will rebuild this code.

Answer (score 0):

Check below one by one:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(DI.PX2,0)) FROM DI WHERE ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(DI.PX2,0)) = 0

SELECT ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(DI.Yield,0)) FROM DI WHERE ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(DI.Yield,0)) = 0

SELECT ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(Dollar_Px,0)) FROM TABLE WHERE ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(Dollar_Px,0)) = 0
```

There must exist any `varchar` string that cannot be converted to `decimal`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an error:

```
(ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+''cpn'' = ''cpn'' OR ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)+''cpn'' = ''0c

pn'') THEN
```

Your Coupon is varchar, but if it's `NULL` you use `0` instead of it.
You should use `'0'` as it's string, not integer, in your `'0cpn'`.

So it should be

```
(ISNULL(DI.Coupon,''0'')+''cpn'' = ''cpn'' OR ISNULL(DI.Coupon,''0'')+''cpn'' = ''0c

pn'') THEN
```

Comment: what ever change you have told to me which i have tried but again throwing error.